# Using Thread in TKinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm working on a Tkinter Desktop Application project. I started stumbling when I need to use Threading which runs the backend code.
I know that in order to share the variables across threads we should be using a global variable. Below is the minimal code.

```
obj = None

class Frame:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.middle_frame = frame
        self.start_button = ttk.Button(self.middle_frame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.start_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.stop_button = ttk.Button(self.middle_frame, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
        self.stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.stop_button.config(state='disabled')

    def start(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_connection)
        self.thread.start()
        self.start_button.config(state='disabled')
        self.stop_button.config(state='normal')
    
    def start_connection(self):
        global obj
        obj = MainManager() # Starts the Backend Loop


    def stop(self):
        global obj
        obj.close_connection() # Want to break the loop here
        self.thread.join()


        self.stop_button.config(state='disabled')
        self.start_button.config(state='normal')
```

While running this code, I get  `obj.close_connection() AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close_connection'`. But I was expecting obj to become as an object of MainManager().
Where am I going wrong? Help me with this.

Comment: Have you examined what `obj` actually is? Apparently it's not what you think it is.

Comment: I resolved it. @Oli 's answer is exactly where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is nothing to do with `tkinter` or really with multithreading. The problem is that `MainManager` has the loop started inside the `__init__` method, something like this:

```
class MainManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True

        # this part runs until stopped
        self.start_doing_stuff()

    def start_doing_stuff(self):
        while self.alive:
            sleep(1)
            print('doing stuff')

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False
```

Here is a code snippet with a similar error to yours:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

obj = None


class MainManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True

        self.start_doing_stuff()

    def start_doing_stuff(self):
        while self.alive:
            sleep(1)
            print('doing stuff')

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False


def test():
    global obj
    print('about to assign to my_global')
    obj = MainManager()
    print('assigned to my_global')


print(f'{obj=}')
t = Thread(target=test)
t.start()
sleep(3)
print(f'{obj=}')
obj.stop()
t.join()
```

Because the `__init__` method doesn't terminate until the `stop` method is called, the call to `MainManager()` in the statement `obj = MainManager()` never terminates, so `obj` is not assigned to. This means that when `obj.stop()` is called, `obj` is still `None`.

This can be fixed my making the `__init__` method terminate, and putting the long-running code into a separate method that is called later:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

obj = None


class MainManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True

    def start_doing_stuff(self):
        while self.alive:
            sleep(1)
            print('doing stuff')

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False


def test():
    global obj
    print('about to assign to my_global')
    obj = MainManager()
    print('assigned to my_global')
    obj.start_doing_stuff()


print(f'{obj=}')
t = Thread(target=test)
t.start()
sleep(3)
print(f'{obj=}')
obj.stop()
t.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was my mistake. Now it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported MainManager, have you run the start_connection()?

Also, you delegate the assignment to a thread. Are you sure this affects the same `obj` as the main thread? Maybe the main thread stays 'none' and the delegate changes the value in a copy. Add a log or print statement and make sure the `obj` gets assigned the `MainManager()` object and print the memory location of that object. In the main class print the memory location of the `obj` variable there as well. Check if it is the same.

This is how you print the memory address of a variable :

```
print(hex(id(your_variable)))
```

Comment: added parenthesis for python 3 otherwise it is the same as python2

Comment: Yes, I started the connection, but I was starting the Backend Loop(infinite) from the __init__(). So, the variable obj was not assigned to the Class (MainManager()).
Now, I changed the code to start the connection and loop in another function and now, it works.
I have figured it out by printing id of the variable.
Thanks man!!